# How to write update query using hibernate +Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

Not supported for DML operations

```
List<LeadsRequest> updateEngg = getEntityManager().createQuery("UPDATE LeadsRequest l set l.status = :status where l.id = :id")
                                .setParameter("status", status).setParameter("id",id).getResultList();
```

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: 
> Not supported for DML operations
> ```

Comment: Please state what you've tried, and ask a clear question. For help: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `getResultList` will obviously not work, that is for `SELECT` queries, use `executeUpdate` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in the java doc for [`Query.getResultList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList()) this is only for `SELECT` statements. It will return the result for the given select query, and as such will not work for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` queries.

For `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` use the [`Query.executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate()) method. Which will run the DML statement and return the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 0):

As M.Denium wrote in his comment you must call `executeUpdate()` instead of `getResultList()`

```
int numberOfChangedEntities = getEntityManager()
    .createQuery("UPDATE LeadsRequest l set l.status = :status where l.id = :id")
    .setParameter("status", status)
    .setParameter("id",id)
    .executeUpdate();
```

`executeUpate()` returns the number of changed entities.